# Laravel-How to merge two collections when one column is common in both collection?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I am using Laravel 5.6.38.

I have two collections.

**Collection 1**

```
[{
"link": "http://example.com/posts/1",
"created_at": "2018-09-20 05:14:10",
"description": "some desc 1",
"post_id": 1,
"priority": "2",
"identifiedBy": "x",

},
{
"link": "http://example.com/posts/2",
"created_at": "2018-09-20 05:14:10",
"description": "some desc 2",
"post_id": 2,
"priority": "3",
"identifiedBy": "x",
}]
```

**Collection 2**

```
[{
"post_id": 1,
"qatagger": "Mr. X"
}]
```

**Expected result**

```
[{
"link": "http://example.com/posts/1",
"created_at": "2018-09-20 05:14:10",
"description": "some desc 1",
"post_id": 1,
"priority": "2",
"identifiedBy": "x",
"qatagger": "Mr. X"
},
{
"link": "http://example.com/posts/2",
"created_at": "2018-09-20 05:14:10",
"description": "some desc 2",
"post_id": 2,
"priority": "3",
"identifiedBy": "x",
}]
```

I tried $collection1->merge($collection2), gets result

```
[{
"link": "http://example.com/posts/1",
"created_at": "2018-09-20 05:14:10",
"description": "some desc 1",
"post_id": 1,
"priority": "2",
"identifiedBy": "superadmin"
},
{
"link": "http://example.com/posts/2",
"created_at": "2018-09-20 05:14:10",
"description": "some desc 2",
"post_id": 2,
"priority": "3",
"identifiedBy": "superadmin"
},
{
"post_id": 1,
"qatagger": "Mr. x"
}]
```

Is there anyway I can get the expected result with out using any loop?

**Update**
*1st join*

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
            ->where('posts.post_status_id', '=', $status)
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw("(SELECT post_id, comment, comment_type FROM comments WHERE comment_id in (SELECT MAX(comment_id) FROM comments
    GROUP BY comment_type, post_id ASC) AND comment_type = 'vip_comment') comments_vip"), 'posts.post_id', '=', 'comments_vip.post_id')
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw("(SELECT post_id, comment, comment_type FROM comments WHERE comment_id in (SELECT MAX(comment_id) FROM comments
    GROUP BY comment_type, post_id ASC) AND comment_type = 'pm_comment') comments_pm"), 'posts.post_id', '=', 'comments_pm.post_id')
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw("(SELECT post_id, comment, comment_type FROM comments WHERE comment_id in (SELECT MAX(comment_id) FROM comments GROUP BY comment_type, post_id ASC) AND comment_type = 'bagging_qa_comment') comments_bq"),'posts.post_id', '=', 'comments_bq.post_id')
            ->leftJoin('users AS identifiedByUser', function($join) {
                $join->on('posts.post_identified_by', '=', 'identifiedByUser.id');
            })
            ->select(['posts.post_id as post_id', 'posts.post_link as link', 'posts.post_status_id as status_id', 'posts.post_description as description', 'posts.post_priority as priority', 'posts.created_at as created_at', 'comments_vip.comment AS vip_comment', 'comments_pm.comment AS 
            pm_comment', 'comments_bq.comment as bagger_qa_comment', 'identifiedByUser.name as identifiedBy'])
            ->groupBy('post_id')
            ->get();
```

*2nd join*

```
$baggers = DB::table('post_baggings')
                    ->leftJoin('posts', 'post_baggings.post_id', '=', 'posts.post_id' )
                    ->join('users AS baggers', function($join) {
                        $join->on('post_baggings.bagging_team_id', '=', 'baggers.id');
                    })->select(array('posts.post_id as post_id', 'baggers.name as bagger'))
                    ->get()->keyBy('post_id');
```

*Merging*

```
$out = [];
    foreach ($posts as $key => $post){
        $post->priority = Priority::where('priority_id', '=', $post->priority)->pluck('display_name')->first();
        $post = new Collection($post);
        $out[] = $post->merge($baggers[$post['post_id']]);
    }
```

Comment: Is this data from a database? If so you probably should do a join instead of merging them afterwards

Comment: @apokryfos, these two are result sets from 2 queries and both of them are complex joins, one is involving 4 tables and one is 3.

Comment: I don't see why that would be an issue.

Comment: @apokryfos I have added my queries, if you can suggest a better solution to it, it will be a great help.

Comment: @apokryfos please let me know, if I should anything more to the question.

Comment: I don't think anything more is necessary. You are already joining multiple tables in your first query, joining one more is not going to change much and can be done in the same way.

Comment: @apokryfos, okay, thank you, I will try again and if I will be successful, I will definitely add it to the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in my comments you can add the table as an extra join in the query to get the results off the database. Something like below would probably work:

```
 $posts = DB::table('posts')
        ->where('posts.post_status_id', '=', $status)
        ->leftJoin(DB::raw("(SELECT post_id, comment, comment_type FROM comments WHERE comment_id in (SELECT MAX(comment_id) FROM comments
GROUP BY comment_type, post_id ASC) AND comment_type = 'vip_comment') comments_vip"), 'posts.post_id', '=', 'comments_vip.post_id')
        ->leftJoin(DB::raw("(SELECT post_id, comment, comment_type FROM comments WHERE comment_id in (SELECT MAX(comment_id) FROM comments
GROUP BY comment_type, post_id ASC) AND comment_type = 'pm_comment') comments_pm"), 'posts.post_id', '=', 'comments_pm.post_id')
        ->leftJoin(DB::raw("(SELECT post_id, comment, comment_type FROM comments WHERE comment_id in (SELECT MAX(comment_id) FROM comments GROUP BY comment_type, post_id ASC) AND comment_type = 'bagging_qa_comment') comments_bq"),'posts.post_id', '=', 'comments_bq.post_id')
        ->leftJoin('users AS identifiedByUser', function($join) {
            $join->on('posts.post_identified_by', '=', 'identifiedByUser.id');
        })
        ->select(['posts.post_id as post_id', 'posts.post_link as link', 'posts.post_status_id as status_id', 'posts.post_description as description', 'posts.post_priority as priority', 'posts.created_at as created_at', 'comments_vip.comment AS vip_comment', 'comments_pm.comment AS 
        pm_comment', 'comments_bq.comment as bagger_qa_comment', 'identifiedByUser.name as identifiedBy', 'joinedTable.bagger as bagger'])
        ->leftJoin(DB::raw('('.
                DB::table('post_baggings')
                    ->leftJoin('posts', 'post_baggings.post_id', '=', 'posts.post_id' )
                    ->join('users AS baggers', function($join) {
                        $join->on('post_baggings.bagging_team_id', '=', 'baggers.id');
                    })->select(array('posts.post_id as post_id', 'baggers.name as bagger'))->toSql()
            .') as joinedTable'), 'joinedTable.post_id', 'posts.post_id')
        ->groupBy('post_id')
        ->get();
```

This is taking advantage of method `toSql` which will preserve the exact query you're doing for your 2nd case. I have not actually tested this however.

A workaround using the resulting collections would be:

```
$result1->map(function ($row) use ($result2) {
      if ($result2->has($row->post_id)) {
         return collect(array_merge((array)$row, (array)$result2)); //Casting to arrays and then to a collection. 
      }
      return collect((array)$row);
});
```

Comment: I am getting errors while using it, I am trying to fix it and let you know, thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: Try the update, I moved everything in the `DB::raw` part, it might work, though not entirely sure.

Comment: Now, this is error free and returning the collections, but not the tagger that we are selecting in our sub query. I am also trying an alternative way with the previous code.

Comment: To get the tagger you might need to add `joinedTable.tagger` in your outer `select(...)` function (as per the update now)

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working, if I will need any modification, I believe I will be able to do it, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can not merge after the result exit, you must merge in your query,
On whatever basis you will be incorporated into this result there is no requirement here.

This Solution but I don't see that true

```
$arr1 = json_decode('[{
"link": "http://example.com/posts/1",
"created_at": "2018-09-20 05:14:10",
"description": "some desc 1",
"post_id": 1,
"priority": "2",
"identifiedBy": "x"
},
{
"link": "http://example.com/posts/2",
"created_at": "2018-09-20 05:14:10",
"description": "some desc 2",
"post_id": 2,
"priority": "3",
"identifiedBy": "x"
}]');

$arr2 = json_decode('[{
"post_id": 1,
"qatagger": "Mr. X"
}]');

$arr1[0] = (object)array_merge((array)$arr1[0],(array)$arr2[0]);
dd(new \Illuminate\Support\Collection($arr1));
```

Comment: Hello Shkry, thank you for your kind effort, I tried your answer, but it did not work for me, but your approach is correct, I am upvoting you, but I have few suggestions, like, I have mentioned, these are collection, to convert to array we can use toArray() and merge it.

Comment: I have posted a working solution, which is just a workaround, not a proper solution, you can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

A work around will be

```
$out = array();
 foreach ($collections1 as $key => $collection1){
      $out[] = (object)array_merge((array)$collections2[$key], (array)$value);
 }

dd(new \Illuminate\Support\Collection($out));
```

A better approach(working solution for now) can be

```
$out = [];
    foreach ($posts as $key => $post){
        $post->priority = Priority::where('priority_id', '=', $post->priority)->pluck('display_name')->first();
        $post = new Collection($post);
        $out[] = $post->merge($taggers[$post['post_id']]);
    }
    
    return new Collection($out);
```

again a workaround.